# How can I get a WPF TextBox to auto resize after a style change?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I have a standard TextBox with a fixed width of `150` and `TextWrapping` set to `NoWrap`, this makes the control behave just like the old WinForms version - which is what I want.

However, when I click a button, I want to effectively 'convert' the TextBox into a label. To save me messing around with multiple controls, I have decide this is best done by changing the style to look like a label. Most of this is working fine, except I want the new style to auto-resize the width of the Control to ensure all text is displayed without the need to drag a selection with the mouse.

In an attempt to do this I have set the `Width` to `auto` and then `MinWidth` to `150`, something like this:

```
<Style x:Key="TypeConfusedTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="150" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
</Style>
```

Which I then assign on button click like so:

```
textBox1.Style = (Style)FindResource("TypeConfusedTextBox");
```

The problem is that after the Style is changed, the control just remains as a fixed width of `150`. If I apply the same `Width` and `MinWidth` values directly to the `TextBox` with the designer (or in the xaml) then is grows as expected when restyled, but so does the original style which I do not want to happen.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm only guessing that you're setting `TextBox.Width` somthing like `<TextBox Width="150" .../>` if that is the case then, according to [Dependency Property Setting Precedence List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx#listing) `Style` won't override your fixed value. Try setting initial `Width` like this:

```
<TextBox>
   <TextBox.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
         <Setter Property="Width" Value="150" />
      </Style>
   </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Good guess, this does fix my issue thanks. I am only just playing with WPF at the moment, when I start a real project I intend to use styles for everything (rather than setting the values inline), but I am glad I tried it this way as now I have learned something important. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The answer by dkozl is exactly the reason why it wasn't working, and is the solution I intend to use.

However, after I posted this question I continued to try a few different things, one of which was to override the width values in code. So just to demonstrate an alternative, here is what I changed my button click code to look like:

```
textBox1.Style = (Style)FindResource("TypeConfusedTextBox");
textBox1.ClearProperty(WidthProperty);//this sets it to "Auto"
textBox1.MinWidth = 150;
```

Again, this is just an alternative, I am not recommending it as the best approach.